# python - index a split string

Tags: python-2.7, indexing, split

I am attempting to .index() a string after I split it with .split(). I am setting the split as a variable in order to use it in the index command, but I am not getting an output if I try and print the index.  Here is a bit of the code I am working on:

```
x_1 = y.split(var_1, 1)[1]
start1 = x_1.index(var_2)
print start1
```

x_1 is the string after the split, with y being the initial string I need to split. var_1 is the location I want to split y at and var_2 is where in x_1 I want to index at.  So, start1 is the index location I want to locate within the split string.

I do this but print does not show up in the output. Any help is appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave some expected input and output strings

Comment: I think you are a bit confused. str.split() does not take a positional index to specify where you want to split it. It takes a separator. So if your string is   `x = 'this is a string'`, and you call `x.split('t')` it will create a list that contains `['', 'his is a s', 'ring']`

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you want to use a different syntax instead of split. This is called slicing. Here is a simple example

```
x = 'this is a string'
start_index = 4
end_index = 12
out = x[start_index:end_index]
print(out)
```

This will give you the output

```
' is a st'
```

This is called 'slicing' a string.

If you just want to get a single character from a string you can use

```
one_char = x[7]
```

to get the 7th character from x.